# For reflexive Banach spaces, boundedness plus closure is equivalent to weak compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I'm reading a proof of some duality at page 33 of [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6FpiqPG4GVDEBk1qgsGU141oVKyxVG-/view) lecture note. There is a paragraph

> For each $\ell$ the sequence $\varphi_k^{(\ell)}-c_X$ is bounded in $L^{\infty}$ so $\overline{\left\{\varphi_k^{(\ell)}-c_X\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}}$ is weakly compact in $L^p(\mu)$ for any $p \in(1, \infty)$ (for reflexive Banach spaces **boundedness plus closure is equivalent to weak compactness**). Let's choose $p=2$ then, after extracting a subsequence, we have that $\varphi_k^{(\ell)}-c_X \stackrel{L^2(\mu)}{\rightharpoonup} \varphi^{(\ell)}-c_X \in L^1(\mu)$ (since $L^2(\mu) \subset L^1(\mu)$ ) for some $\varphi^{(\ell)} \in L^1(\mu)$.

Here $\varphi_k^{(\ell)}, c_X \in L^p (\mu)$. A convex set is closed in weak topology IFF it is closed in norm topology. However, a set closed in norm topology is **not** necessarily closed in weak topology. It seems to me the bolded sentence is meant that

> In a reflexive Banach space, if a set is bounded in norm and closed in weak topology then then it is compact and sequentially compact in weak topology.

Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem

Comment: For weak sequential compactness you need reflexivity plus separability.

Comment: @geetha290krm Theorem 3.18 in Brezis's *Functional Analysis* does not require separability. Could you have a check on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZq6W.png)?

Comment: You are right. I missed the fact that the proof actually reduces to a separable subsapce.

Comment: Weak compactness and weak sequential compactness are always the same: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem